# Why are the bit lengths of keys and digests equal in Lamport signatures?

Tags: hash, post-quantum-cryptography, one-way-function, hash-signature, key-size

In Lamport's one time signature scheme:

- One way function to convert a pseudo random number private key to a public key takes $\{0,1\}^n$ and returns $\{0,1\}^n$.
- Cryptographic hash function to convert message into message digest takes $\{0,1\}^*$ and returns $\{0,1\}^n$.

Why are these two not independent? Why do they need the same number of bits $n$?

Comment: Having them be independent makes the scheme take a little longer to describe. ​ ​

Comment: But the security is same even if number of bits is different, right?  We can have smaller signatures if number of bits in the message digest and each key is different.

Comment: No. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Can you please explain little elaborately? "little longer to describe" seems trivial. I would like to understand this before moving to winternitz.

Comment: An adversary could forge by finding a collision _or_ breaking the candidate-OWF. ​ When your compression function is independent of your candidate-OWF, those two tasks will be independent of each other. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Yes. I agree. But why should the number of bits be same? They are independent functions.

Comment: Letting "the number of bits be same" lets the security parameter just be that number, and avoids needing to decide what to call the extra variables. ​ ​

Comment: So if you have a 384-bit $G$ that maps your message onto a digest which represents a subset of the 768 elements of $\text{sk}$, an attacker could break that. OR, they could pivot to attacking the mere 256-bit $F$ which you convert your private $\text{sk}$ into public $\text{pk}$ with. (But the latter attack, they'd have to repeat close to 384 times, no?) So would it not be efficient to skimp on $F$? Every bit you trim off _it_ seems to do little to help the attacker, but saves you as many bits as $G$'s output *has* in storage and transmission of $pk$…

Answer (score 1):

The security level of a hash function is determined by its output size. In general, a hash function is considered cryptographically secure when it is collision resistant and provides security level $b = n/2$. Hence, it is not wrong to describe Lamport's scheme that way. However, the description probably was done that way to abstract away some details:

If you want to get $b$ bits security and do a classical message digest, you will need a hash function with $m = 2b$ bit outputs for the digest. However, for the "internal" hash function used to map secret key elements to public key elements you are fine with $n = b$ bit outputs as you just need one-wayness for this function. Now, if you change the message digest to a randomized message digest using $h = H(R,M)$ for randomness $R$ and message $M$, you can get away with $m = n = b$ bit output length for the message digest (if you do everything correctly). This is more about the message digest than about the hash function used inside of Lamport and hence distracting from the actual topic: How does Lamport's scheme work.